# Cannot access modem page directly, only through router

Tags: networking, modem

I have 3 modems. Two are dying, so I bought a third one of a different brand. On the old modems, I could tell if they were working or not by accessing the config page. When they stopped working, if I plugged into them directly (or through the router) and tried to access that page they wouldn't show up.

On the new modem, I can't access the page unless I'm attempting through my router. What the heck is going on? Any Google search on the topic gives the reverse situation.

- The pages all have the same address, 192.168.100.1 .
- The two dead/dying ones are model Motorola MB7621.
- The new one is a Netgear CM700.
- They are all modem-only units.
- My router is a Google Wifi puck. I can still access my local devices when the internet is out.

Comment: Edits removing unrelated extra info.

Comment: *" I can't access the page unless I'm attempting through my router."* -- That is an incomplete negative description.  You probably have to configure the network interface of your PC to have a *static* IP address.  When the router is connected, the PC is "automatically" obtaining a *dynamic* IP address from the DHCP server in the router.  Without the router, there is no DHCP server, no IP address for the PC, and hence no network access by the PC (although you do not specifically describe that as a symptom).

Comment: Lack of DHCP from the router was what I initially thought as well, but that doesn't explain why I could access the modem config page on the Moto modems with no cable line attached to it and the PC set to get IP through DHCP.

Comment: I can connect and get the modem config page on the Netgear now. I'm unsure why, as the only thing that has changed is a correction of the MAC address registered with my ISP. Maybe that had somehow affected the modem and caused the issue, but it's a bit of a stretch.